Three topologies on the space of sections of a vector bundle
Let $E\to M$ be a Riemannian vector bundle over an oriented Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with a connection $\nabla$. Let $\Gamma(E)$ denote the vector space of sections of $E\to M$. For $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$, its Sobolev $k$-norm $(k=1,2,\dots)$ is defined by $$ |\sigma|_k^2:=\int_M ||\sigma||^2+||\nabla \sigma||^2+\cdots+||\nabla^k \sigma||^2 v_g$$
where $v_g$ is the volume form of $M$. The completion of the space $V^k(E):=\{\sigma \in \Gamma(E):|\sigma|_k<\infty\}$ is denoted by $W^k(E)$.
I want to compare three different topologies on $V^k(E)$.

By definition of $W^k(E)$ we have $V^k(E)\subset W^k(E)$, and the norm $|\cdot |_k$ on $W^k(E)$ defines a topology on $W^k(E)$, and hence on $V^k(E)$.

Second, since $\Gamma(E)$ is a vector space it has a topology: the  weak topology determined by all finite-dimensional subspaces (cf. Infinite Dimensional Topological Vector Space). Since $V^k(E)\subset \Gamma(E)$, we have another topology on $V^k(E)$.

Finally, there is a topology $V^k(E)$ induced by the $C^\infty$-topology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies#Whitney_C%E2%88%9E-topology) of $C^\infty(M,E)$.


Are these three topologies the same? Is there a "natural" choice of a topology of $\Gamma(E)$ that are used commonly?

These topologies are all distinct, as can be seen by considering the trivial vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, the space $V^k(E)$ is the same as the space $V := C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap W^{k, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with bounded $W^{k, 2}$ norm. Then we see that:

The norm $|\cdot|_k$ is the $W^{k, 2}$ norm on $V$.

To see that the topology (2) is not equal to the topology (1), it suffices to exhibit a subset $C \subseteq V$ which is closed in (2) but not in (1). Let $C = \{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an algebraic basis of $V$. Then for any finite-dimensional subspace $W \subseteq V$, the intersection $C \cap W$ is finite, hence closed in $W$. So $C$ is closed in (2). But it is not difficult to find a basis $C$ which is not closed in (1). (Hint: Find a sequence of linearly independent elements $v_i \in V$ which converge to $0$, and extend $v_i$ to a basis of $V$.)

The $C^\infty$-topology is the union of the $C^k$-topologies, where the $C^k$-topology is defined to be the topology generated by the basis
$$
B(f, \delta) = \{g \in V \mid \text{$|\partial^\alpha f - \partial^\alpha g| < \delta$ for all $|\alpha| \leq k$}\},
$$
where $f \in V$ and $\delta : \mathbb{R}^n \to (0, \infty)$ is a continuous function.
A similar argument as before shows that (3) is not equal to (2). To show that (3) is not equal to (1), it is not difficult to exhibit a sequence which converges in (1) but not in (3). Alternatively, we can see that (3) is not first countable (and thus not metrizable) as follows. Let $\delta_k : \mathbb{R}^n \to (0, \infty)$ be a countable family of functions. Then choose $\delta : \mathbb{R}^n \to (0, \infty)$ such that for all $k$, there exists a point $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\delta(x_k) < \delta_k(x_k)$. Then it is straightforward to check that $B(0, \delta)$ does not contain any of the sets $B(0, \delta_k)$, so in particular $0 \in V$ does not admit a countable neighborhood basis.


Note that similar arguments can be used to show that the three topologies are distinct for any vector bundle $E$ (except for trivial cases).
I don't have a great answer for what the most natural topology on $\Gamma(E)$ is. It seems there are several different topologies which are useful in different situations, analogous to the way that many different function spaces in analysis are useful.

That being said, (2) is certainly not a useful topology. This should not be surprising given that the definition of (2) does not in any way depend on the vector bundle $E$.
The $C^\infty$-topology, sometimes called the strong $C^\infty$-topology is used, though I personally have not seen it very much. One reason it is nice is that many natural classes of maps are open in the $C^\infty$-topology; for instance, the set of immersions $\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is open in the space $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ with the $C^\infty$-topology.
A related topology (which I have seen quite often) is the $C^\infty_\mathrm{loc}$-topology, sometimes called the weak $C^\infty$-topology. This topology is best described as the topology of local uniform convergence of all derivatives. Note that the $C^\infty$-topology and the $C^\infty_\mathrm{loc}$-topology agree when the manifold $M$ is compact.
The $W^{k, 2}$-norm topology on the completion $W^{k, p}(E)$ of $\Gamma(E)$ is quite useful in situations where it is desirable for the space of sections to be a Banach space. In particular, when everything is a Banach space, one gets access to the inverse function theorem, which leads to a rich theory of infinite-dimensional manifolds. Infinite-dimensional manifolds can be quite useful in finite-dimensional differential geometry; e.g., they show up in symplectic geometry and gauge theory when one wants to show that certain moduli spaces are finite-dimensional smooth manifolds.
One can of course also define a $W^{k, p}$-norm for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. There is also the space $W^{k, p}_\mathrm{loc}(E)$ of sections which are in $W^{k, p}$ on compact subsets, where the topology is given by $W^{k, p}$-convergence on compact subsets.

